webrtc peer mediaStream received but not being played
so, I'm trying to make a video Calling app on my own to learn about webRTC and when I'm trying to test it on two different devices, both their own camera stream does play on the screen, but not the other device(other candidate of video call). I've logged the Mediastream being received and it does exist, here is a part of the media stream
{
contentHint: "",
enabled: true,
id: "7b00ae89-cb98-4c95-b221-eefe508ec17c",
kind: "video",
label: "7b00ae89-cb98-4c95-b221-eefe508ec17c",
muted: false,
oncapturehandlechange: null,
onended: null,
onmute: null,
onunmute: null,
readyState: "live",
stats: null,
[[Prototype]]: 
MediaStreamTrack
length: 1
}

here is the part of the code

        newPeer.ontrack = async (e) => {
          setFriendStream(e.streams[0]);
          if (friendVideo.current.srcObject && friendVideo.current.srcObject.id === e.streams[0].id) {
            console.log('Duplicate stream received, ignoring...');
            return;
        }
          if (friendVideo.current) {
            // Log the tracks to see if a video track is present
        const videoTracks = e.streams[0].getVideoTracks();
        if (videoTracks.length > 0) {
            console.log('Video track found:', videoTracks[0]);

            friendVideo.current.srcObject = e.streams[0];

            try {
              console.log('Friendvideo srcObject', friendVideo.current.srcObject);
              
                await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 50)); // Short delay before playing
                await friendVideo.current.play().then(_=> console.log("video playing")).catch(er=> console.log(er));;
                console.log("Friend's video is playing");
            } catch (playError) {
                console.error("Error playing friend's video:", playError);
            }
        } else {
            console.warn('No video track found in remote stream.');
        }
          }
        };

I've tried a simple
if (friendVideo.current) {
friendVideo.current.play()
}

I've tried to ask chatGPT, due to which the code is at this stage.
I've tried video element being muted and unmuted. I can't figure out why the Mediastream is not playing.
I don't receive any error but,the video doesn't play and what I've noticed is that I never receive any log from the .then() or .catch() of the friendVideo.current.play() or any other log after it
